# Node.js: maintaining cookies with http request session

Tags: node.js, http, session-cookies

I have to code a client for a legacy HTTP API that is maintaining the state on the server by using session cookies.

I hoped for a simple solution like

```
const http = require('http');
http.request(options, callback);
```

but it appears that the built-in http module does not provide a built-in cookie state management. There are many posts here at stackoverflow where it is suggested to use `require` module with cookie jar, but the module's site says that this module is now officially deprecated.

I am not too enthusiastic about coding all that `set-cookie` response header parsing and providing a valid `cookie` header in requests. There surely must exist some library that allows to handle this cookie maintenance with ease. What would be the go-to module now that `request` is no longer the one?